# Hook before all delyed job success callback to save successfully completed jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

**Objective:**

To save successfully completed jobs

**Methods used**

Have looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28217770/1610034) which tells how to save completed jobs and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16639849/1610034) which suggests to create a plugin which will be executed after one of lifecycle events.

**Problem**

There are following lifecycle events, and applicable arguments as present in [code](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/master/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb):

```
  :enqueue    => [:job],
  :execute    => [:worker],
  :loop       => [:worker],
  :perform    => [:worker, :job],
  :error      => [:worker, :job],
  :failure    => [:worker, :job],
  :invoke_job => [:job]
```

I had expected there will be some event corresponding to success, I am not getting **which one will be  executed after job is successful.**

**Some Code**

With the help of above tow answers, I have created this plugin to save completed job and put in *config/initializers/save_completed_delayed_job.rb*

```
module Delayed
  module Plugins
    class SaveCompletedDelayedJobPlugin < Plugin
      callbacks do |lifecycle|
        # see below for list of lifecycle events
        lifecycle.after(:perform) do |job|
          p "This should be ran after success so that I can save the job in different table"
          CompletedDelayedJob.create({
            priority: job.priority,
            attempts: job.attempts,
            handler: job.handler,
            last_error: job.last_error,
            run_at: job.run_at,
            failed_at: job.failed_at,
            completed_at: DateTime.now,
            queue: job.queue
            })
          end
      end
    end
  end
end

Delayed::Worker.plugins << Delayed::Plugins::SaveCompletedDelayedJobPlugin
```

**Why I need plugin**

I can not use callback methods as I don't have dedicated job classed, I am using following code to queue job.

```
handle_asynchronously :deliver_delayed, :queue => 'my_q'
```

Comment: is your `after(:perform)` block getting run at all? Maybe you could fire some `done` event manually at the end of the `perform` method, or write some `JobRunner` class which does this automatically (it can be run asynchronously, then run the actual job synchronously).